# Dynamically loading class values in C++

Tags: c++, class

I'm fairly new to C++ and and trying to create an epic RPG. The game has four players, each of which has an instance of class Character containing all info (name, level, hp, etc).

```
class character
{
public:
    string name = "Nameless";       
    int hp = 10;
    int mp = 5;
}
```

Somewhere else in the code I create playing characters with instances of this class:

```
character player1;
character player2;
character player3;
character player4;
```

During combat I will need to be able to change player values dynamically. I have two specific questions:

- How can I change the HP of a randomly selected character? (string =  "1"; player[string].hp = 0;)
- How can I dynamically choose the class value to be loaded? (string = "hp"; player1.[string] = 10;)

Perhaps I should be using something else than classes for this, open to suggestions :)

Cheers!

Comment: Use a collection of objects instead of individual variables. `std::vector<character>` is a reasonable choice.

Comment: Seems reasonable - would you mind providing short usage examples specific to my situation? I've googled this for a bit and can't really figure it out yet

Comment: I would recommend one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) over googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I change the HP of a randomly selected character? (string = "1"; player[string].hp = 0;)

To easily select a random player to modify, the easiest approach is to place all players in a container such as a vector. Then you can generate a random index into the vector and modify the player at that position.

> How can I dynamically choose the class value to be loaded? (string = "hp"; player1.[string] = 10;)

To dynamically choose which property you wish to modify there are a few approaches. An easy solution is shown below with a mapping from string property names to property values. Another approach is to create an enum class which enumerates the different properties and then use that as a key instead of strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

class character
{
    public:
        std::string name = "Nameless";
        std::unordered_map<std::string, int> properties{
            { "hp", 10 },
            { "mp", 5 }
        };
};

void print_players(const std::vector<character>& players) {
    for (const auto& player : players) {
        std::cout << player.name;
        for (const auto& property : player.properties) {
            std::cout << ", " << property.first << "=" << property.second;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto players = std::vector<character>{
        character{"Player 1"},
        character{"Player 2"},
        character{"Player 3"},
        character{"Player 4"}
    };

    print_players(players);

    auto rng = std::default_random_engine{std::random_device{}()};

    // Select a random player
    auto random_player_distribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{0, players.size() - 1};
    auto& random_player = players[random_player_distribution(rng)];

    // Select a random property
    auto random_property_distribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{0, random_player.properties.size() - 1};
    auto random_property_iterator = random_player.properties.begin();
    std::advance(random_property_iterator, random_property_distribution(rng));

    // Modify random property
    random_property_iterator->second = 42;

    print_players(players);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change the HP of a randomly selected character? (string = "1"; player[string].hp = 0;)

Use an array instead of variables:

```
character players[4];
```

You can also add references to players if you need them:

```
character &player1 = players[0];
character &player2 = players[1];
character &player3 = players[2];
character &player4 = players[3];
```

> How can I dynamically choose the class value to be loaded? (string = "hp"; player1.[string] = 10;)

Initially you can't.

Try using dictionary if you need, or overload `[]` operator in the class.

Anyway, it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: C++ doesn't have any STL class called "dictionary", so I guess you meant `std::unordered_map` ;-)

Comment: @underscore_d, I didn't marked the word "dictionary" as inline code. I ment any dictionary-like object. Yes it can be `map`, `unordered_map` or anything else including custom classes.

Comment: Could you please provide a usage example of unordered_map in this context? After extensive googling I still quite can't figure it out

Comment: @AlexanderWolff, I think you already have it in the other answer.